# Why doesn't PHPUnit see Laravel Facades?

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I have problem with PHPUnit testing and Laravel
Exception: Class 'DB' not found

**My TestCase file:**

```
namespace Tests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase as BaseTestCase;

abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication;
}
```

**My CreatesApplication file:**

```
namespace Tests;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel;

trait CreatesApplication
{
    public function createApplication()
    {
        $app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

        $app->make(Kernel::class)->bootstrap();

        return $app;
    }
}
```

**This is my Test:**

```
namespace Tests\Unit;

use App\Services\RepetitionService;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class RepetitionServiceTest extends TestCase
{
   public function testGetNextIteration()
   {
       $repetitionService = new RepetitionService;

       $nextIteration = $repetitionService->getNextIteration(1);
       $this->assertEquals(2, $nextIteration);
   }
}
```

**Method that is being tested:**

```
public function getNextIteration(int $lastIteration) : int
    {
        // some example code (method is not real but code below copied from original method)
        \DB::table('cards')->get();
        Config::get('params.repeat_iterations');
        config('params.repeat_iterations');
    }
```

**Commend:**
`php vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --configuration phpunit.xml tests/Unit`

**Versions:**
laravel 7
PHP 7.4
PHPUnit 9

Comment: Try to `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;` and the just `DB::table(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use DB from this path

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```